# sed / awk - remove all but a specific matching pattern from a file

Tags: string, makefile, sed, awk

I want to convert a makefile like this:

```
test.o: var_one.h var_two.h

test2.o: another_header.h var_three.h archive/something_random.h
```

to this:

```
test.o: var_one.h var_two.h

test2.o: var_three.h
```

ie, I want to remove any filename that doesn't start with the search string "var_"

I can't seem to find a lot of information for sed about pattern matching when not wanting the search string?

Comment: Nothing other than sed or awk? A scripting language, may be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need awk for this type of job. With sed, attempting to remove words that don't match a string would be a painful (and probably ugly) script to write.

```
awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)$i !~ /var_.*\.h/ && $i=""}1' Makefile
```

#### Input

```
$ cat Makefile
test.o: var_one.h var_two.h

test2.o: another_header.h var_three.h archive/something_random.h
```

#### Output

```
$ awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)$i !~ /var_.*\.h/ && $i=""}1' Makefile
test.o: var_one.h var_two.h

test2.o:  var_three.h
```